# How to use setContentView() in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, setcontentview

I have a listview with footer in an activity.

What I want to do is:

1. Make a listview.
2. Add textviews to listview's footer
3. Apply footer to listview.

Below is activity's `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_refer_room);

    // making listview...
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.referList);
    ...
    ...
    String[] from = {"line1", "line2"};
    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mapList,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);

           // footer_layout is in refer_footer.xml
     View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.refer_footer, null, false);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);

    TextView tv= new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(element.text());
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ll.addView(tv);


        listView.addFooterView(footer);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_refer_room);
    }
}
```

Therer are two .xml files.(one for activity that contains listview, one for footer)
To add textview, I use `setContentView(R.layout.refer_footer);` and textview was added sucessfully. But when I run a app, it only displays the content of footer.(not listview) So I use `setContentView(R.layout.activvity_lecture_refer_room);` then app displays nothing.

What should i do to display lsitview containing footer?

Comment: Make a layout XML that has the exact view you want and then set it using `setContentView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
setContentView(R.layout.refer_footer);
```

No need to call `setContentView` with `refer_footer` layout because `refer_footer` layout is for ListView footer which you are adding  using `addFooterView` :

```
// inflate foooter layout 
 View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.refer_footer,
                                                             null, false);
  // get footer_layout from footer
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)footer.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);
    // create TextView
    TextView tv= new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(element.text());
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // add textview to footer_layout
    ll.addView(textview);
    // set layout for footer
    listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Comment: it occurs `NullPointerException` in `ll.addView(tv)`

Comment: @user3858358: show updated code and make sure you are doing as `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)footer.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);`

Comment: @user3858358: in which layout xml `footer_layout` id exist ? in  `refer_footer.xml`  or in `activity_lecture_refer_room` ?

Comment: I did exactly same as what you answered - `footer_layout` is exists in `refer_footer.xml`

Comment: `View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.refer_footer, null, false);
            
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);
            
TextView textview = new TextView(this); 
ll.addView(textview);
listView.addFooterView(footer);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @user3858358: why you are not updating question because you are still not doing as i'm suggested in answer

Comment: @user3858358: remove first  `// adding textview dynamically
    setContentView(R.layout.refer_footer);

    // footer_layout is in refer_footer.xml
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);

    TextView tv= new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(element.text());
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ll.addView(tv);


     setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_refer_room);` code and then use my suggest code

Comment: @user3858358: why you are not using `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)footer.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);` instead of `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);` ??

Comment: sorry about my carelessness